# Solr facet search for comma separated field and facet result should be display filter of search field

Tags: solr

I have indexed with comma separated values
ex: "Content Distribution,Content Marketing,Email,Marketing" using "PatternTokenizerFactory". while doing facet am getting

- Content Distribution-1
- Content Marketing-1
- Email-1
- Marketing-1

Excepted:
when search "Content Distribution" the facet field should be display

- Content Distribution-1
- Content Marketing-0
- Email-0,
- Marketing-0

using edismax. If we are using solr facet.prefix I'm getting because I need search prefix and suffix edit distance for facet autocomplete.

Comment: _Why_ should the field display that? Since the values are comma separated, and you are indexing them as separate tokens - that seems to indicate that they mean the same thing. Why should one be 1 and the other zero? Why can't you use facet.prefix as you're saying? If you need separate parameters for edit distance and auto complete compared to your display values, make two requests.

Comment: ya,Sorry field should not display. basically i need facet autocomplete search. The conditions is that search anywhere and edit distance . when i do facet.perfix is working same as i need suffix and edit distance. can you please suggest how to use two request for edit distance

Comment: Do one request with `facet.prefix` and one without?